# Using "homepage" in package.json, without messing up paths for localhost

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

This question actually follows directly from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43011112/3391108) on a previous question.

I added a `"homepage"` to my `package.json` because it is a React app that I hosted on Github Pages. The output of `npm run build` say that the `/build` directory can now be deployed, and it assumes the project is being hosted at `/project_name/`.

But on localhost, the project is *not* being hosted at `/project_name/`, so the paths being requested for js and css are messed up (looking for `/project_name/static/...` instead of `/static/...`) and the app broken.

How can one have the homepage field in package.json so that they can deploy to Github Pages (for example) while still develop locally with a working app?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I use express on my server. I resolved the issue by having my client served from the built-in dev server that create-react-app gives you (connecting on your standard localhost:3000), but then also spinning up my express server on localhost:9000 and having my client point API calls to that port when in development. So index.html, assets, etc. served by create-react-app's built-in server, and API calls served from my own server on a different port. So I have 2 servers going in development. But on prod, my express server serves the client (index.html, assets, etc.) from the build directory.

Answer (score 120):

[Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) for `create-react-app` explains how to serve same build from different relative paths.

If you put homepage as

```
"homepage": ".",
```

assets will be served relative to `index.html`. You will then be able to move your app from `http://mywebsite.example` to `http://mywebsite.example/relativepath` or even `http://mywebsite.example/relative/path` without having to rebuild it.

For development purposes, serving using `yarn start` or `npm start` is good enough. App will be available in localhost

Comment: The answer doesn't match the question.

Comment: This is not recommended by react guys... https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1487#issuecomment-277727669

Comment: @NadeemJamali A few comments after that one they mention officially releasing this feature https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1487#issuecomment-278871994, but note that it doesn't work well with client side routing.

Comment: It looks like this article gets homepage to work with client side routing: https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

Comment: @Rohmer, you're right. They did have a pull request for it.

I'm not sure about client side routing with CRA. It has always been a pain for me.

Comment: @Rohmer, I was running in this issue due to the port number in my URL. After all, I included the port number in the value of "homepage", then it starts working...

Comment: this works but creates another issue, after deploying when we try to refresh it shows white screen

Comment: This worked for me while hosting my app in AWS S3 within a sub folder of S3 bucket.

Answer (score 62):

You can use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable to override the homepage for a specific build.
Even better have it set in your package.json, for instance:

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-localhost": "PUBLIC_URL=/ react-scripts build"
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I've been trying this and while it seems to work to some extent (app is now hosted at "/"), anywhere in my code that referrs to %PUBLIC_URL% or process.env.PUBLIC_URL still gets the value set in the "homepage" attribute in package.json. However if I change it in a .env file, it does change those variables. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this worked for me! gh-pages requires the homepage value in package.json so it's kinda annoying that it breaks other things but this worked!

Comment: Works fine. When I npm start, the browser opens pointing to this variable. Thanks!

Comment: On my Windows setup PUBLIC_URL=/ is translated to %2520, so I just write PUBLIC_URL=  (empty space) and it works

Comment: For me the perfect solution to keep the "homepage" and to local with "start" working is:

{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PUBLIC_URL='.' react-scripts start"
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}

Answer (score 22):

For an all-in-one answer which *also* covers react-router-dom:

1. Add `package.json['homepage']` to be your production URL. To be noted, the CRA build step removes the domain part of the URL to leave only the path to index.
2. When building for localhost, do `PUBLIC_URL=/ npm run build`
3. Add `<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%" />` in your `public/index.html` page as proposed in [this article](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/) ; it will provide support for assets (img, CSS) and will expose the `%PUBLIC_URL%` to be reused later.
4. In the component which creates your BrowserRouter *(typically App.js or main.js)*, add:

   ```js
   const basename = document.querySelector('base')?.getAttribute('href') ?? '/'
   ```
5. use as: `<BrowserRouter basename={basename} />`

Comment: This is default used by Visual Stuido now

Comment: This worked beautifully without having to have the production folder or PUBLIC_URL all over the codebase. Note that I didn't need to adjust when building for localhost since CRA automatically adds the production folder to the URL when opening the browser.

Answer (score 9):

You can override the homepage setting using you dev shell environment:

```
$ export PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:3000/ 
$ yarn start
```

or if you prefer, remove your homepage setting and configure your env before building for production:

```
$ export PUBLIC_URL=http://example.com/subdir 
$ yarn build
```

Comment: Setting homepage in package.json never worked for me, but this did.

Comment: " export PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:3000/ " this command worked for me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what the top answer said, the `homepage: "."` option works if using `create-react-app`, but not if you are using Vite. For Vite, you have to add `base: "./"` to the `vite.config.js` and it will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where an image would not appear once I added 'homepage' to my package.json and deployed it to gh-pages. After trying many different solutions, I finally solved this by taking the image out of the public folder and into the src folder. Then I switched:

```html
<img src="/img/image.JPG" alt="image" />
```

to

```html
<img src={require('../../assets/image.JPG')} alt="image" />
```

This seemed to do the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `'homepage'` key in the `package.json` file pointing to the `github pages` or your website URL.

Only then the relative path will be set to the 'Public' directory and all paths becomes relative to the assets used.

To avoid localhost problem, create `.env` file in the project directory with the following content `PUBLIC_URL="."` this will make sure the localhost paths are not messed up.