# how to fix 404 not found in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

when I directly visit 'https://xyz/login', it shows error '404 not found' but it redirect me to 'https://xyz/login' after logout from home page ('https://xyz/').
This problem starts after the deployment of my create-react-app. we used nginx server for deployment.

Comment: did you try adding "homepage":"."   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost

Comment: Here is simple article to fix this issue. We can solve this issue for any SPA frameworkhttps://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/14/how-to-fix-404-page-not-found-error-after-build-in-angular-or-react-or-vue-js/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544199/how-to-make-create-react-app-return-404-for-resources-that-does-not-exist-on-it/68544318#68544318

Answer (score 0):

Edit nginx/sites-available/default in **VIM** OR **nano** which ever you prefer, on your server machine.

```
vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Change below

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

> but it redirect me to 'https://xyz/login' after logout from home page ('https://xyz/').

*You are able to access login* from the logout button because 'create-react-app' and BrowserRouter are only active and able to do routing from / i.e. homepage. If you go to /someLink your server does not know what to do with it, then it read a rule to go to 404 error. The above changes all requests to always going to your homepage, that way BrowserRouter can take it from there.

If you want to read more about the issue, check out this question:
[Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

side note: SEO wise, google still crawls SPAs, but checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snapshot for SPA optimization.

Answer (score -1):

Set basename in BrowserRouter.

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/xyz'>
  <Route exact path='/' /> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: can you elaborate  @anil