# Return 404 error in React application when resources do not exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to merge an HTML/CSS admin template that I have bought online, into my CRA app.

The problem is that when I add the CSS of that template into my `index.html` inside the `header` section, and the CSS file does not exist, the server returns the home page.

I know this behavior is required for SPA, that server should return the home page for all routes, because routes are handled on the client-side, but in this case, I need to temporarily disable this feature and ask the server to return 404 if it does not find the resource.

How can I do it in create-react-app?

Comment: What do you mean by return `404`? Are you referring to the response status code? If so, then it is not possible unless you are using your app along with a custom server. You cannot modify response status code/headers from the client code. If you just want to show a page showing that the resource doesn't exist then refer the [react-router documentation/examples](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233324/how-to-add-http-headers-in-react-js-apps-response

Answer (score 0):

Create a 404 component. something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

const 404NotFound = () => {
  return <h1>404 Error</h1>;
}

export default 404NotFound;
```

Import the file inside your react routes configuration file something like this.

```js
import 404NotFound from './404NotFound';
```

Include in your switch something like this after all the routes:

```js
<Switch>
    ... other routes
    <Route component={404NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't send any HTTP headers, it's only for displaying a "404 not found" type of template to users.