# Images are not visible in react-native app release build

Tags: android, react-native

Prepared a release build (android) in react native but local images are not visible. I tried some solutions suggested like running the command - `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` but still images are not shown in the release build. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not so familiar with react-native.. But did you try having "homepage":"."  in your package.json? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "hack" for this

Use `android:largeHeap="true"` inside Android Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild the application as because, Android Studio maintain the cache memory when apk buil

Answer (score 0):

How you import the local image. This code works fine to import an image:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import test from '../images/test.png';
<Image resizeMode='cover' source={test} />
```

Comment: My code to show image is like - `<Image resizeMode='contain' style={styles.logoImage} source={require('./Images/logo.png')}/>`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following?

1. delete the react native bundle files
2. Run `./gradlew clean` in the terminal
3. try running `react-native run-android --variant=release`