# in ReactJs src/index.js isn't being executed at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started Learning React a few months ago then quitted. And today, I decided to come back to it so I did:

```
npm init
npm install
npm start
```

Everything went fine (No Errors) except that nothing is being rendered on the screen! So I tried logging something inside `src/index.js`... with nothing being logged to the console.
I also tried attaching the debugger after adding a breakpoint inside `src/index.js` and it never got there.

I am very new to React so it might be a stupid question but any help will be great.

Index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my src/index.js:

```
imports...

console.log("index.js");

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Hellow World</h1>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Update1**

Here is my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/AmerAlahmar/random-quote-machine2/tree/feature-add-api-call) link, heads up; I simplified my code to make the question clear.

Comment: there is a typo `<dev>` should be `<div>`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I updated the question.

Comment: how are you initializing this project?  create react app?  linking to react cdn in index.html?  your index.js is linked in your html file, yes?

Comment: When I firat created it I used `npx creat-react-app` but then when I came back to it I cloned it from github

Comment: can you share your repo link or check what is there in   "main" of package.json.   "main": "index.js". as I just ran your code. it looks fine.

Comment: Sure @KushalSeth, I am updating my question to add my repo link.
and also `package.json` contains: `"main": "index.js"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MUHAMMAD said, The problem occurred because I had my `"homepage":"..."` in my `package.json` set to my Github `README` file. like this:

```
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AmerAlahmar/random-quote-machine2#readme"
```

I am not sure why and when did that happen but according to this [article](https://www.andreasreiterer.at/fix-whitescreen-static-react-app/), a simple "." fixed it:

```
  "homepage": "."
```

This might lead you to the next question: What if I want to host my React app on Github while still work on it locally?

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost) and this [article](https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Your repo is working fine on sandbox environment
check you local configuration
like node etc..

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/AmerAlahmar/random-quote-machine2