# How to set context root of a ReactJs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to set the context root of a react app to `"/myApp"`, so the app link will be `"https://mydomain/myApp"` instead of `"https://mydomain"`. I tried to set `basename` for `Router`, but it didn't work. Not sure what I missed. Here is the code snippet.

```
import './styles/style.less';
import React from 'react';
import { render as renderToDOM } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/Home';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { commonReducer } from './reducers/commonReducers';
import { authReducer } from './reducers/authReducers';
import { regionReducer } from './reducers/regionReducers';

const { container } = global;
container.style.display = null;

const reducers = combineReducers({
  commonReducer,
  authReducer,
  regionReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

render();

function render() {
  try {
    renderToDOM((
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router basename='/myApp'>
          <Route path='/'>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </Provider>        
    ), container);
  } catch (e) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      // TODO show an application error display
    }
    throw e;
  }
}
```

With the code above, the app still loads at `"https://mydomain"`. When I hit `"https://mydomain/myApp"`, it throws 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Have you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost#

Comment: Were/aare you hosting/serving the React app from `"https://mydomain/myApp"`? Has the  hosting service/server been configured correctly? This isn't really much of a React app problem. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to gather a sense of all the different ways all the different hosting services and server may need to be configured/setup.