# How to force ReactJS to ignore the homepage value in development?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In package.json I have the homepage set to be "/subfolder"
That should be true only for the production build. When I develop I would like it to be: localhost:3000, or so I hoped
It seems when I add homepage value it also take effect when I do `npm start` not just `npm run build` .
Is there any way to force this only on none dev builds?

```
create-react-app -V
3.4.1
```

Comment: Looks like this answer might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/64416044/4668680.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using \`"homepage"\` in package.json, without messing up paths for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost)