# How to support react js app for 2 different sub domains

Tags: reactjs, subdomain

I am a bit struggle with support to a react js to support 2 different subdomains. Followings are the subdomains I need my app to support

- www-dev.somedomain/apps/myapp
- app-dev.somedomain/myapp

As you can see, react-app-path is also changing with the subdomains. I have defined PUBLIC_URL and REACT_APP_PATH in my .env file as below.

```
REACT_APP_PATH=/myapp
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
PUBLIC_URL=/myapp
```

With above env vars app-dev... URL is working. If I change to the path to `apps/myapp` then www subdomain in working. I need a way to support both subdomains at once

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem with the following steps; I was using Nginx to be redirected to the same host. The problem I have was with the paths.

- `www-dev.somedomain/apps/myapp`
- `app-dev.somedomain/myapp`

According to my Nginx configurations, both URLs were redirected to `/` in the server. Then the app couldn't find the static files because paths were different with domains. So to fix this, I did as below.

- First, remove `PUBLIC_URL` from my env file. Then app files will be hosted at the `/` location
- Added `homepage` attribute to `package.json` file. adding homepage will serve assets relative to index.html. Read more about homepage. [Using `"homepage"` in package.json, without messing up paths for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost)
- Since the app is using internal routing, I added simple Nginx rule to rewrite the location of static files as below.
  `rewrite /static/(.*)$ /static/$1 break;`

This solved my problem with supporting two doamins.

Comment: That's a smart solution, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

No way, Your React app will be compiled into static HTML, JS, and CSS files, and the only time you can pass parameters to the build tool is before building, which is what you're doing right now. Once the building is complete, it can't be changed.

You can write two shell script, with different environment variable. Then invoke each of them will build different web app.

Comment: I found an article, but I am not sure whether it will work for my case or not http://nael.io/2016-12-29-subdomains-with-express-and-react-router/

Comment: @PubuduJayasanka it let server to remap the request url. Perhaps it will work,

Comment: I was able to solve this problem with the homepage attribute and a simple Nginx rewrite rule. Thanks for the help