# How to fix the Refused to execute script error in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error with my Reacjs application with the production build.

> Refused to execute script from
> 'https://www-xxxx.com/apps/someapp/settings/static/js/52.eebbab07.chunk.js'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
> type checking is enabled.

This error occurred due to URL change with client-side routing in my application. I used the following attribute in my package.json file.

```
  "homepage": ".",
```

The static files are located in `https://www-xxxx.com/apps/someapp/` path. Is there a way to control this behaviour which happened with internal routing and the homepage attribute?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because when the homepage attribute is defined, assets will be served relative to index.html. Then what happened was my application had internal routing implemented. So it broke the application because then the app is looking at static files in the wrong location.

Files were stored in the `https://www-xxxx.com/static` and my app was searching those files in `https://www-xxxx.com/apps/someapp/settings/static/`. As long as you have only one route like below
`https://www-xxxx.com/settings`
then you won't get any errors with relative way.

You can read this question as well. [Using `"homepage"` in package.json, without messing up paths for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost)

I solved this error with a simple Nginx rewrite.

`rewrite /static/(.*)$ /static/$1 break;`