# react-app is (not) running on localhost:3000/*github link*

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

So I got a very weird problem, I just initialized my app using npx create-react-app, deletec unnecessary files, made an eslint and prettier config and ran the app and I see two problems here, the first is my app doesn't display App.js content, and the second is that 'link' to my app is not just localhost:3000 as always, it is

```
http://localhost:3000/*github username*/*repo name*
```

Someone had a problem like this?
What can I do?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207

Comment: Oh that was exactly that, thanks. I didn't know how to describe my problem in google so I came here and asked.

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was about a package.json config, for unknown reasons homepage was set to my github repo link, I just changed it to

```
"homepage": ".",
```