# When trying to add hompage to package.json and run npm run build, it shows /

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am stuck! I have been looking on google and can't find the answer... Hope someone ran into this problem?

I added my domain to package.json

[image]

but when I npm run build, I get the
"The project was built assuming it is hosted at /".

Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone run into this issue? :( It should say my domain but it doesn't...

Thank you all!

Comment: have you set PUBLIC_URL?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so? I am still learning react.js. Can you guide me or do you have something I can read about this? Thank you!

Comment: Would you share full file json file?

Comment: please check this answer once - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Thank you Bharat for pointing that out.

Create .env and add PUBLIC_URL=https://

Thank you!