# how to have `npm start` initially open a different webpage?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have consolidated my static webpages into the `public/` directory in my `create-react-app`, and I have the `index.html` which is meant to be a dynamic user page (that I am configuring with react). I want one of my static webpages to initially boot up and display when the app first loads up. How can I accomplish this with minimal change of source code? I don't want to have to reconfigure everything; I just want `npm start` to boot up something other than `index.html` initially, which is under `public/home-page/home-page.html`.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you will have to locate your `package.json` in your `/root` directory then set the key `main` to the value `public/home-page/home-page.html` at the first level block.
**The `main` property will will serve your app to the set value**

```
{
    "main" : "public/home-page/home-page.html",
}
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Kindly update the question with your package.json

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `homepage` in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "your-app-name",
  ...
  "homepage": "/home-page/home-page.html",
  ...
}
```

Comment: i'm a bit confused by the absolute path referencing. How does that work within react?

Comment: also, this solution doesn't work. it still boots up at the `index.html` that react supplied.

Comment: Would this helps you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost

Comment: i looked at that thread and a few others and none helped